# Do I need to run supervisor if I set queue driver to sync in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with a laravel application and I want to set my queue driver to sync, but even after setting it, I am having to run supervisor to process the queue which doesn't make sense to me. So I am not sure if it worked or not.

Do I need to run `php artisan queue:listen` when queue driver is set to sync? Or have supervisor running in the background?

Comment: No, you should not need to run any command to execute jobs on the sync driver. How are you dispatching the jobs?

Comment: using the `dispatch` helper function

Comment: Oh okay, I figured it out, someone hardcoded `database` in the queue config file. -_-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you do not.
If you use the sync driver everything should happen in the same request - in sync.

Further reading: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#introduction

Comment: using 5.2 but makes sense what you are saying. but it doesn't work for me. I am still having to run queues to make the jobs work. I even tried running `config:clear`